# PHP MySQL UPDATE query not working (no rows returned)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having troubles using the `UPDATE` query from a MySQL function in PHP. I'm not making any syntax error, but it simply don't return any row (I'm echoing the result rows and it always says 0). My code is the following:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE wecode.users SET activate = 1 WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND email = '$email'", $connection)
or die ("Troubles activating the account ".mysql_error());
return mysql_affected_rows();
```

I tried putting the same query (using actual column's values) in my Workbench, and it works fine (at least the query return 1 result row). So, any idea of what is the problem?

Comment: If this is a new application, you should not be using `mysql_query`, and you must [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/) all values.

Comment: Do some debugging. Assign your UPDATE statement to a variable first `$sql = "UPDATE...";` then echo it `echo $sql`. And show us what you've got.

Comment: If you set a column to the value it already has, that counts as 0 rows affected. So make sure you're updating a row that doesn't already have `activate = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_affected_rows` to indicate that user was activated by this query.

It will returns 0, if user doesn't exist or user was already activated (*activate=1*).

[PHP Manual - mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value
>   is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that
>   mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows
>   matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the
>   query.

Comment: You are right. You and Barman are right. I was trying to update the column value with the same value, so the function mysql_affected_rows returned 0.

Thank You so much. And thank all of you for answering.